# Python PIL issue | OSError: cannot open resource

Tags: python, pandas, python-imaging-library

I'm running a python script to generate certificates. However I'm getting this error:

```
Initializing Script!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Generate_certificates.py", line 31, in <module>
    main() 
  File "Generate_certificates.py", line 12, in main
    font = ImageFont.truetype(r".\Dancing_Script\DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", 150)
  File "/home/rohit07/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 855, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/rohit07/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 852, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/rohit07/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 211, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: cannot open resource
```

The file structure inside the folder is:

[image]

The script:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import pandas as pd

def main():
    print("Initializing Script!")
    names = pd.read_csv('dummy_names.csv')
    for i,row in names.iterrows():
        name = str(row['FName']) + ' ' + str(row['LName'])
        name = name.title()
        empty_img = Image.open("empty-cert.png")
        font_size = 150
        font = ImageFont.truetype(r".\Dancing_Script\DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", 150)
        W,H = empty_img.size 
        w, h = font.getsize(name)
        width = ((W-w)/2)
        height = ((H-h)/2)-50
        if W%w >= 2:
            font_size = 130
            width = ((W-w)/2) +75
            height = ((H-h)/2)-10

        font = ImageFont.truetype(r".\Dancing_Script\DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", font_size)
        image_editable = ImageDraw.Draw(empty_img)
        image_editable.multiline_text((width,height), name, (35, 57, 75), font=font)
        empty_img.save("{}.jpg".format(name.replace(" ", "_")))
        if i % 50 == 0: 
            print('Processed {} Rows'.format(i))
    print("Process Complete!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want use a custom font for the name so I'm using *Dancing Script* font. I checked whether there are any typos somewhere but still I'm unable to troubleshoot.

Comment: try using absolute path or `/` instead of ``\``

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @alex's comment

I changed:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(r".\Dancing_Script\DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", 150)

font = ImageFont.truetype(r".\Dancing_Script\DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", font_size)
```

to:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(r"./Dancing_Script/DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", 150)
font = ImageFont.truetype(r"./Dancing_Script/DancingScript-VariableFont_wght.ttf", font_size)
```

and it worked!